# Java 8 Explicit 'this' Parameter

Tags: java, parameters, java-8, this

I recently heard that it is possible since Java 8 to define an explicit parameter called `this` in instance methods, like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public void test(Test this, int i) { System.out.println(i); }
}
```

What is the use for this kind of syntax?

As you can clearly see in this screenshot (Eclipse, compiler compliance Java 8), this is valid syntax.

[image: Proof]

Comment: What would be the purpose of such declaration?

Comment: Just as a sidenote: internally the compiler will change all instance methods to have a _this_ parameter but that's just how methods are enabled to operate on instances. That's something the compiler will do implicitly and not a developer explicitly. If developers where allowed to do that as well, they'd probably break the compiler.

Comment: As you might be able to tell, that image is from the source code of a compiler, so I already know how `this` and instance methods work on the JVM. That is why the syntax makes sense, since `this`, the 0th parameter, is now explicit.

Comment: When trying this in Eclipse Luna with Java 7, I get an error: _Explicit declaration of 'this' parameter is allowed only at source level 1.8 or above_. Indeed it seems that this is possible.

Comment: This code will not compile, error `<identifier> expected`

Comment: It's called a receiver. It's specified in JLS 8, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1-220) (scroll up for syntax).

Comment: @MaxZoom you need to use Java 8 for this to work.

Answer (score 7):

For Java 7 or prior, you cannot use `this` as name of a variable because it's a [reserved keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html). What you can do is to pass `this` as parameter into a method:

```
class Test {
    public void foo(Test test, int i) {
        //...
    }
    public void foo(int i) {
        foo(this, i);
    }
}
```

For Java 8, refer to [Why can we use 'this' as an instance method parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24291091/1065197)

Comment: This is not correct, I attached an image to the question that clearly shows you can (Even in a interface).

Comment: @Clashsoft **For Java 7 or prior**. Your code compiles for Java 8...